# how to sort multidimensional associative array in php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I have an array like below. I want to sort this multidimensional associative array using max price value.

```
<?php
    $car = array
        (
        '0' =>
        array('RoomType' => array
                (
                'price' => array(
                    'max_price' => '200'
                )
            )
        ),
        '1' =>
        array('RoomType' => array
                (
                'price' => array(
                    'max_price' => '400'
                )
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
```

Can you please help me on this regards? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please explain your question

Comment: i want to sort this array using the max price value. can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the answers to [previous questions on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+sort+multidimensional+array)? If so, is there something particular you are stuck on which these did not help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort them by price by using `array_multisort()`. Consider this example:

```
$cars = array (
    '0' => array(
        'RoomType' => array (
            'price'=> array('max_price' => '200' )
    )
),
'1' => array(
    'RoomType' => array (
        'price'=> array( 'max_price' => '400' )
    )
),
'2' => array(
    'RoomType' => array (
        'price'=> array( 'max_price' => '100' )
    )
),
'3' => array(
    'RoomType' => array (
        'price'=> array( 'max_price' => '50' )
    )
)
);

$price = array();
foreach($cars as $key=> $value) {
    $price[] = $value['RoomType']['price']['max_price'];
}

// for ascending use SORT_ASC 
// for descending, use SORT_DESC
array_multisort($price, SORT_ASC, $cars);

print_r($cars);
```

Sample Output:

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [RoomType] => Array
                 (
                     [price] => Array
                         (
                             [max_price] => 50
                         )

                 )

         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [RoomType] => Array
                 (
                     [price] => Array
                         (
                             [max_price] => 100
                         )

                 )

         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [RoomType] => Array
                 (
                     [price] => Array
                         (
                             [max_price] => 200
                         )

                 )

         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [RoomType] => Array
                 (
                     [price] => Array
                         (
                             [max_price] => 400
                         )

                 )

         )

 )
```

Comment: @ArzonBarua your welcome, if it did help you kindly upvote/accept so that others may see it as valid if they stumble upon this similar question it may help them too :) good day

Comment: I am sorry. I did not notice that and thanks again.. :)